# Simple question about Sitecore's publish:end:remote event

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Anyone have luck with the **publish:end:remote** Sitecore event or can shed some light on how it's supposed to work? I simply cannot get it to fire.

From what I understand, it's an event that will trigger after a successful publish to a remote instance of Sitecore. The trouble is, there appears to be no documentation on which server(s) this event is fired on (master or slave) or which server should contain the config setting.

I have the "History Engine" enabled on both of my servers for all databases like so:

```
<Engines.HistoryEngine.Storage>
  <obj type="Sitecore.Data.$(database).$(database)HistoryStorage, Sitecore.Kernel">
    <param connectionStringName="$(id)">
    </param>
  </obj>
</Engines.HistoryEngine.Storage>
```

As a test, I added a custom class to the publish:end:remote event on both servers. The class simply logs "Hello World" via Log.Info(), but nothing shows up.

I am using Sitecore 6.4.1 (rev. 101221).

### ***UPDATE 1***

I have read the latest Scaling guide and instituted all of the required configuration changes. Both our single Staging/CM server and (2) Prod/CD servers have EnableEventQueues set to true and the ScalabilitySettings.config is in place on all instances. That said, ***I believe the issue is that Sitecore is storing these queued events in the core database***. Our CD servers are isolated from the staging core database and they are only linked to Staging via the "web" database. Should I be storing these queued events in the production 'web' database like so...

```
/eventing/providers/add[@name="sitecore"]
```

... and set the following attribute: systemDatabaseName="<strike>*core*</strike>***web***"

### ***UPDATE 2***

I have set the eventing provider to use the (shared) production 'web' database and I now see event queues pouring into the EventQueue table. There are around 60 records for the "PublishEndRemoteEvent" event in that table at any given time. All of these events have the "InstanceName" set to my Staging instance name. "RaiseLocally" is set to FALSE and "RaiseGlobally" set to TRUE. **Oddly, the "Created" date for new events are somehow 7 hours in the future.** Our Staging server is located only 3 hours ahead of where I work. I'm thinking this time difference might be the culprit.

Answer (score 6):

Be sure you have the "EnableEventQueues" setting set to true in **both** web.config files. You'll find it in the /sitecore/settings section of the web.config.

See my post in this thread on the SDN forum for more details:
http://sdn.sitecore.net/forum//ShowPost.aspx?PostID=34284

You may also want to check out the Scaling Guide document on SDN (it was recently updated):
http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/scaling_guide_sc63-64-usletter.pdf

Comment: Thanks aweber1, we have EnableEventQueues set on both our Staging server and our (2) CD production servers. I am going through the scaling guide and checking things off.

Comment: Please see the update to my initial question. I've added a bounty to the question as well. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Time you looking at is stored in UTC. Because of this you shouldn't have problems even if your servers are situated on different continents.